# Unpredictable request payload structure but Need to create user from it

Tags: laravel, http, request, payload

My system can get request from multiple sites and request payload will have user details. However, the structure or format of payload can be different and not known. My system shall extract out the details from it and create user in to my system.

e.g. one request source will send first name as fname='abc' and other might send it as first_name='abc'.

I have to implement it in PHP laravel

Answer (score 0):

This would resolve your issue:

```
$name = null;
if(!empty($data['fname'])) {
   $name = $data['fname'];
} elseif(!empty($data['first_name']) {
   $name = $data['first_name'];
}
```

Then you can execute validation, autofill and things like that to create or modify your user model.

Comment: Thank you for responding but we can not predict if it can be fname or first_name or anything.